# Gomoku (Connect Five) Minimax algorithm not finding obvious win

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, minimax, gomoku

I'm developing a very simple connect five (gomoku) AI for fun in Javascript using minimax and alpha beta pruning. I've just been following some tutorials online, but for some reason I can't quite get it to work. I think I have a logical bug somewhere, because in the following code, there is a fork if the AI places a piece in the second row and third column, but it's not being found as the `bestMove`.

Weirdly enough, if I set a breakpoint, that position (`row: 1, col: 2`) is often found as the `winningMove`, but for whatever reason, the minimax function never calculates `bestMove` to be that move, even though I believe it clearly should be. That is, if the AI places a piece there, it's basically an immediate win next turn, because it causes a win in multiple directions.

That is, if the AI places a move at the white 2, then there can either be a vertical win, or a horizontal win, in the next AI move, because the human could only block one of them:

[image]

```js
const ROWS = 9;
const COLS = 9;
const LEN = 5;

const EMPTY = 0;
const HUMAN = 1;
const COMP = 2;

function checkDirection(grid, who, currChain, sRow, sCol, incRow, incCol) {
  let newChain = 0;

  while (currChain + newChain < LEN) {
    const row = sRow + (incRow * (newChain + 1));
    const col = sCol + (incCol * (newChain + 1));

    if (grid[row * COLS + col] !== who) {
      break;
    }
    
    newChain++;
  }

  return newChain;
}

function lineCheck(grid, who, sRow, sCol, mRow, mCol) {
  let chain = 1;

  chain += checkDirection(grid, who, 0, sRow, sCol, mRow, mCol);
  chain += checkDirection(grid, who, chain, sRow, sCol, -mRow, -mCol);

  return chain >= LEN;
}

function isWinningMove(grid, who, row, col) {    
  return lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 1, 0) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 0, 1) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 1, 1) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, -1, 1);
}

function getTile(grid, row, col) {
  if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= ROWS || col >= COLS) {
    return -1;
  }

  return grid[row * COLS + col];
}

function hasNeighbor(board, row, col) {
  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }

  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col) > 0) { return true; }

  if (getTile(board, row, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }

  return false;
}

let bestMove = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

function minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, player, latestRow, latestCol) {
  if (depth === 0) {
    return evaluatePlayerBoard(board, player, player === COMP ? HUMAN : COMP, latestRow, latestCol);
  }

  if (isWinningMove(board, player, latestRow, latestCol)) {
    return 1000000;
  }

  if (player === COMP) {
    let maxEval = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        const idx = row * COLS + col;
        const tileValue = board[idx];

        if (tileValue > 0 || !hasNeighbor(board, row, col)) { continue; }

        board[idx] = player;
        const evaluation = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, HUMAN, row, col);
        board[idx] = tileValue;

        if (evaluation > maxEval) {
          maxEval = evaluation;
          bestMove = idx;          
        }

        alpha = Math.max(alpha, evaluation);

        if (beta <= alpha) {
          return maxEval;
        }
      }
    }

    return maxEval;
  } else {
    let minEval = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        const idx = row * COLS + col;
        const tileValue = board[idx];

        if (tileValue > 0 || !hasNeighbor(board, row, col)) { continue; }

        board[idx] = player;
        const evaluation = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, COMP, row, col);
        board[idx] = tileValue;

        if (evaluation < minEval) {
          minEval = evaluation;
        }

        beta = Math.min(beta, evaluation);

        if (beta <= alpha) {
          return minEval;
        }
      }
    }

    return minEval;
  }
}

function evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, who, latestRow, latestCol) {
  let idx = 0;
  let score = 0;

  if (isWinningMove(grid, who, latestRow, latestCol)) {
    return 1000000;
  }

  for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if (grid[idx] !== who) { idx++; continue; }

      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col + 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col + 1) === who) { score++; }

      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col) === who) { score++; }

      if (getTile(grid, row, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row, col + 1) === who) { score++; }
      
      if (getTile(grid, row, col) === who) { score++; }

      idx++;
    } 
  }

  return score;
}

function evaluateBoard(grid, you, opponent, latestRow, latestCol) {
  return evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, you, latestRow, latestCol) - evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, opponent, latestRow, latestCol);
}

const exampleBoard = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
];

minimax(exampleBoard, 2, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, COMP, -1, -1);

console.log(bestMove);
```

You can run the snippet above and see that `20` is logged instead of `11`, even though `11` is clearly the better move as it causes an immediate win.

Comment: At a guess, when searching, it doesn't count how many wins can be had from a given move, just that a win is possible.

Comment: @Ouroborus is that necessary for correctness / for it to work properly? I just assumed that since it will see that placing a piece at index 11 will result in a guaranteed win even if they try to block, that it will be the highest value option. Wouldn't that be "worth" more than a win that could potentially be blocked?

Comment: I think that partially depends on what the depth is set to.

Comment: Well even when I set depth to 6 (and this victory condition should only require a depth of 2, right?), it still doesn't seem to find it

Comment: The win happens on the third move. Both sides' placements are counted towards that. Not sure why it wouldn't find with 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- With `const val = evaluatePlayerBoard(board, player, player === COMP ? HUMAN : COMP, latestRow, latestCol);` you pass 2 player arguments, while the function only expects one player argument. So the arguments are misinterpreted by the function and the result is useless.
- Probably related to the above: you have a function `evaluateBoard` which is never called, but which does expect two player arguments. I guess you intended to call *that* function from `minimax`.
- Still `evaluateBoard` returns a score that is *relative* to the first player argument (positive is better), but since you have a maximizing player and minimizing player, the sign of the score should not be dynamically determined by the *arguments* to this function, but "hard-coded" in such a way that COMP always gets the positive score, and HUMAN the negative. So `evaluateBoard` should actually get no player argument at all, and just make the first call to `evaluatePlayerBoard` with `COMP` as argument, and the second one with `HUMAN` as argument.
- `minimax` calls `isWinningMove` with the wrong player argument. It should be the opponent that played the last move, since that is the move that is passed as argument.
- With `depth` starting at 2, you only allow for a move of COMP and a return move of HUMAN. Then you evaluate the position. At that time there is no win yet. You should start with a `depth` of at least 3
- As `bestMove` is a global variable, you'll sometimes get the best move of the deeper move of COMP, since no matter what the depth is, you will overwrite it. But this deeper move is not the move you want to identify. Best practice is to **not** use a global variable for this. Instead, make `minimax` return both the found *value* as the corresponding *move*. You can combine both in an array (or plain object), like this: `return [maxEval, bestMove]`. This means you have to change your code in several places: all `return` statements in `minimax` should return an array now, and all calls of `minimax` should expect an array as return value, and pick the part they are interested in (either the value or the move).
- When `minimax` sees the depth is zero, and detects a win by calling `isWinningMove`, it always returns 1000000, but it should return -1000000 if the last move was played by HUMAN. So move this logic inside both `if` and `else` blocks.
- Less an issue, but it only requires one more line so that `minimax` can also return the best move for when `HUMAN` would be the initial caller. I would just add it.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```js
const ROWS = 9;
const COLS = 9;
const LEN = 5;

const EMPTY = 0;
const HUMAN = 1;
const COMP = 2;

function checkDirection(grid, who, currChain, sRow, sCol, incRow, incCol) {
  let newChain = 0;

  while (currChain + newChain < LEN) {
    const row = sRow + (incRow * (newChain + 1));
    const col = sCol + (incCol * (newChain + 1));

    if (grid[row * COLS + col] !== who) {
      break;
    }
    
    newChain++;
  }

  return newChain;
}

function lineCheck(grid, who, sRow, sCol, mRow, mCol) {
  let chain = 1;

  chain += checkDirection(grid, who, 0, sRow, sCol, mRow, mCol);
  chain += checkDirection(grid, who, chain, sRow, sCol, -mRow, -mCol);

  return chain >= LEN;
}

function isWinningMove(grid, who, row, col) {    
  return lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 1, 0) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 0, 1) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, 1, 1) || 
         lineCheck(grid, who, row, col, -1, 1);
}

function getTile(grid, row, col) {
  if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= ROWS || col >= COLS) {
    return -1;
  }

  return grid[row * COLS + col];
}

function hasNeighbor(board, row, col) {
  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }

  if (getTile(board, row - 1, col) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row + 1, col) > 0) { return true; }

  if (getTile(board, row, col - 1) > 0) { return true; }
  if (getTile(board, row, col + 1) > 0) { return true; }

  return false;
}

// Removed global bestMove definition from here

function minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, player, latestRow, latestCol) {
  if (depth === 0) {
    // Fixed: Call different function and don't pass player arguments:
    const val = evaluateBoard(board, latestRow, latestCol);
    return [val, -1]; // Now returns a pair (value, move)
  }

  const opponent = player === COMP ? HUMAN : COMP; // Moved this expression here
  let bestMove = -1; // Is now a local variable -- not a global.
  if (player === COMP) {
    // Fixed: player argument should be opponent, and return statement should be different per player
    if (isWinningMove(board, opponent, latestRow, latestCol)) {
      // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
      return [1000000, -1]; // Positive for COMP, negative for HUMAN.
    }
    let maxEval = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        const idx = row * COLS + col;
        const tileValue = board[idx];

        if (tileValue > 0 || !hasNeighbor(board, row, col)) { continue; }

        board[idx] = player;
        // As minimax returns an array now, get the first element of it
        const evaluation = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, HUMAN, row, col)[0];
        board[idx] = tileValue;

        if (evaluation > maxEval) {
          maxEval = evaluation;
          bestMove = idx;        
        }

        alpha = Math.max(alpha, evaluation);

        if (beta <= alpha) {
          // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
          return [maxEval, bestMove];
        }
      }
    }
    // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
    return [maxEval, bestMove];
  } else {
    // Fixed: player argument should be opponent, and return statement should be different per player
    if (isWinningMove(board, opponent, latestRow, latestCol)) {
      // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
      return [-1000000, -1]; // Positive for COMP, negative for HUMAN.
    }
    let minEval = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
        const idx = row * COLS + col;
        const tileValue = board[idx];

        if (tileValue > 0 || !hasNeighbor(board, row, col)) { continue; }

        board[idx] = player;
        // As minimax returns an array now, get the first element of it
        const evaluation = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, COMP, row, col)[0];
        board[idx] = tileValue;

        if (evaluation < minEval) {
          minEval = evaluation;
          bestMove = idx; // Also track best move for HUMAN.
        }

        beta = Math.min(beta, evaluation);

        if (beta <= alpha) {
          // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
          return [minEval, bestMove];
        }
      }
    }
    // Minimax returns an array now: value, move
    return [minEval, bestMove];
  }
}

function evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, who, latestRow, latestCol) {
  let idx = 0;
  let score = 0;
  if (isWinningMove(grid, who, latestRow, latestCol)) {
    return 1000000;
  }
  for (let row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if (grid[idx] !== who) { idx++; continue; }

      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col + 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col + 1) === who) { score++; }

      if (getTile(grid, row - 1, col) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row + 1, col) === who) { score++; }

      if (getTile(grid, row, col - 1) === who) { score++; }
      if (getTile(grid, row, col + 1) === who) { score++; }
      
      if (getTile(grid, row, col) === who) { score++; }

      idx++;
    } 
  }
  return score;
}

function evaluateBoard(grid, latestRow, latestCol) { // Removed player paramaters
  // Hardcoded the player arguments, as COMP is maximizing, and HUMAN is minimizing.
  return evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, COMP, latestRow, latestCol) 
       - evaluatePlayerBoard(grid, HUMAN, latestRow, latestCol);
}

const exampleBoard = [
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
];

// The depth should be set at least at 3 to detect the win.
// As minimax returns an array now, get the move part of it (at index 1)
const bestMove = minimax(exampleBoard, 3, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, COMP, -1, -1)[1];    
console.log(bestMove); // 11
```

Disclaimer: I only verified your code to resolve the question you asked about. There might still be other issues you need to fix.

Comment: Oh my thank you so much!! This is so helpful you have no idea. I was really stuck on this and in hindsight it looks like I made some dumb mistakes while trying out various different things, but you also caught a bunch of things that would have stumped me for a while. Thank you thank you thank you thank you thank you!!!

Comment: Hiya, I was playing around with this a bit more, and I noticed that if you set the depth from 3 to 5, it changes the best move from `11` to `21`, but I think `21` is a weaker move because it doesn't result in an immediate win? Do you have any idea why that might be happening? I assumed that with more depth that it would make a better move, no?

Comment: This happens because there is no logic in your code that will give preference to quick wins over slower wins. You can achieve this by reducing a bit the absolute value of the value you get back from a recursive call. This requires that you have enough room in the absolute value to reduce it, so you then must avoid that a score is just 1. So maybe calculate a score that is a multiple of 10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! Do you think I could just multiply `1000000` by `(depth + 1)`? Would that work? Because then quick wins would be worth more? Like doing return `[1000000 * (depth + 1), -1];` instead of `return [1000000, -1];`

Comment: Hmm, actually I just tried that and it didn't seem to work, but not sure why..

Comment: No, no, not that way. You must adapt the `score`, and you must **diminish** the value you get back from recursion. If you cannot make it work, even after researching it, feel free to ask a new question, including your best attempt, and someone will look at it (if not anyone else, I will).

Comment: Ah okay yeah I'll give it a try. I think I need to mess with things a bit anyway because I think something's still quite not right. Like, if the `HUMAN` player has 4 in a row with open ends on each side (or even 3 in a row with open ends on each side), the computer doesn't even try to block it, even when I set the depth to >= 5, so for some reason the computer doesn't seem to care about stopping the HUMAN from winning at all

Comment: But yeah I'll look into it for a few hours and try to figure it out.. I think maybe the core minimax algorithm might still be a bit buggy? And if I still can't get it at that point I'll post a new question

Comment: Yes, as I wrote at the end, I only looked at the problem raised in the question.

Comment: Ah okay sorry. Okay thanks then! I will investigate what else could be wrong and then probably post a new question in a few hours if I can't quite get it.